# Git branch name in Bash prompt

Tags: bash, git

I have been trying to get the Git status on my bash prompt but haven't had any success.  The color variables work so it's not them.  Here is my PS1 and parse function.

```
PS1="${GREEN}ganymede@${BLUE}dawson:${ICYAN}\W${RESET}${IYELLOW} $(parse_git_branch) $ " 

parse_git_branch() {
     git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}
```

What is missing from my PS1?

Thanks
Dawson

Comment: For installed git clients, it has a function `__git_ps1` which returns the branch or hash of `HEAD` in brackets. It's often used in `PS1`. The function also prints extra status indicating rebase, sparse checkout, conflicts.

Answer (score 5):

The line:

```
PS1="$anything"
```

or:

```
PS1="$(command)"
```

written this way means: *evaluate `$anything` now* or *run `command` now*, i.e., at the time you're setting the variable `PS1`.  Let's suppose that `$anything` or `command` prints `hello`.  The final result is:

```
PS1=hello
```

after which the prompt you'll get is the constant string `hello`.

You'd like `PS1` to contain, among other things, the string `$(parse_git_branch)`.  That means you *must quote the dollar sign*, e.g.:

```
PS1=\$\(parse_git_branch\)
```

or:

```
PS1="\$(parse_git_branch)"
```

or:

```
PS1='$(parse_git_branch)'
```

If you're willing to let *all* `$var` expansions take place later, the single quote method is simple and effective.  If you want some expansions to take place now, consider, e.g.:

```
PS1="${GREEN}ganymede@${BLUE}dawson:${ICYAN}\W${RESET}${IYELLOW} \$(parse_git_branch) $ "
```

or:

```
PS1="${GREEN}ganymede@${BLUE}dawson:${ICYAN}\W${RESET}${IYELLOW} "'$(parse_git_branch) $ '
```

Note that the unquoted `SPACE$SPACE` in some of these is "safe" because `$SPACE` remains unchanged during expansion.